# how to excluding global filter for a single controller

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'am using Myth-Auth library for my Codeigniter 4 project and I'am enable before login filter globally. So if anyone want to access  any controller if they're not logged in will redirect to login page.
My project is an IoT project and I made 1 controller to handle data from NodeMCU. but because i enable the login filter globally, my nodemcu can't access this controller and always redirect to login page.
**so my question is how to excluding this global filter only for single controller?**
    thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

already solved
just add except option on filter config

```
public $globals = [
    'before' => [
        'login' => ['except' => ['/Hub/*']] //just add like this
    ],
    'after' => [
        'toolbar'
      ]
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run any filter as global, the $globals array should include all the methods that are to be excluded. When I did as suggested in the supplied answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65316873/9663356) I got a cyclical redirect on login - because the filter kept redirecting to a method login that was not marked as excluded in the globals array.

I am using IonAuth authentication library, so my $globals array now looks like this:

```
    public $globals = [
    'before' => [
        'checkLogin' => [
            'except' => [
                //method I wanted publically available
                'calls/public', 
                //IonAuth methods that should be publically available
                'auth/login', 
                'auth/forgot_password',
                'auth/reset_password',
                ]
            ] //just add like this
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'csrf',
    ],
    'after' => [
        'toolbar',
        // 'honeypot',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by it and its work fine in my case.

```
  public $globals = [
    'before' => [
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'csrf',
        // 'invalidchars',
        // 'dates',
        'isLoggedIn'=> ['except' => ['login','/']],
        // 'IPBlocker'
        // 'APIBlocker',
    ],
    'after' => [
        'toolbar',
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'secureheaders',
        // 'dates',
        // 'LoginFilter',
        // 'APIBlocker',

    ],
];
```