# How do I know which controller is currently running in the BaseController?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I want to check that a user is logged into my app directly in the **initController** method of the **BaseController** and redirect them to an OIDC authentication mechanism (**AuthController**) if not logged in.

If I run the following code, my script obviously loops to itself.

BaseController.php

```
public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        if (!session()->userLogin) {
            //no user logged in
            $this->response->redirect(site_url('/auth'));
        }
    }
```

So, how can I prevent AuthController redirecting to itself?

Should I override the **initController** method in **AuthController** or can I check the name of the current controller or route in the **initController** of **BaseController** with `get_class($this);` ?

Which is the most appropriate?

Comment: You could also apply a [global filter](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html#returning-response) that does that.

Comment: @SimonWeber, excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for to replace the hooks from CI3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way to do it, like sayd by @simonweber, is to use the **global filters**, with an **EXCEPT directive**.

It has been anwswered already here :

[how to excluding global filter for a single controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306152/how-to-excluding-global-filter-for-a-single-controller)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a route check to your `if` condition.

```php
!session()->userLogin && !str_contains(current_url(), site_url('/auth'))
```